# Why is this bash IF statement not working?

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
if [[ $DATA == *?xml* ]]
then
    if [[ $DATA == *misuse* ]]
    then echo "Misuse" >> $OUTPUTPAST2
    else echo "All Good" >> $OUTPUTPAST2
    fi
else echo "Not xml" >> $OUTPUTPAST2
fi
```

Where `$DATA` does not contain the string `?xml`I am expecting an output of `Not xml`, but I am getting output of `All Good`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since there's no shebang, are you sure it's being run by Bash?

Comment: Yes, I just hadn't included the shebang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is special character in glob which means match any single character.

Use it like this:

```
if [[ "$DATA" == *'?xml'* ]]
then
    if [[ "$DATA" == *misuse* ]]
    then echo "Misuse" >> $OUTPUTPAST2
    else echo "All Good" >> $OUTPUTPAST2
    fi
else
    echo "Not xml" >> $OUTPUTPAST2
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

While quoting the question mark will suffice to solve your immediate problem, this looks like code which really really wants to be a `case` statement instead.

```
case $DATA in
    *'?xml'*misuse* | *misuse*'?xml'*)
              echo Misuse ;;
    *'?xml'*) echo All Good ;;
    *)        echo Not xml;;
esac >>$OUTPUTPAST2
```

Notice also how the redirection can go after the entire block, to avoid a lot of repetition.

(If "misuse" can only go after the "?xml" marker, you can simplify.)

Comment: Does it take the statements in order and stop iterating when it finds a match? The first two are not exclusive...

Comment: I don't understand the question.  There is no "iteration" but yes, it proceeds down the case list until it finds a case which matches, then leaves the switch statement after performing the block in that case.  How are "the first two not exclusive"?  As far as I can tell, I have implemented exactly the same logic as in your nested `if` maze.

Comment: I've not come across case before so am asking about it rather than critiquing your code. I mean that if '?xml' and 'misuse' exist in $DATA then aren't both expressions met? In which case does it exit as soon as it meets one expression? (and it seems from your reply that the answer is yes.)

Comment: Yes, the first branch is taken if both are present. There are two alternate wildcard expressions to cover any ordering; the last sentence tries to explain that you can remove one of them if the order is known, or you don't want the case to trigger for one of the alternatives.